# numpy - Python - Selectively import parts of the .txt file

Tags: python, numpy, analysis

In my data.txt file, there are 2 types of lines.

1. Normal data: 16 numbers separated by spaces with a '\n' appended at the end.
2. Incomplete data: In the process of writing the data into data.txt, the writing-in of the last line is always interrupted by the STOP command. Thus, it is always incomplete, e.g.it can have 10 numbers and no '\n'

**Two questions:**

**a. How can I import the whole file EXCEPT the last incomplete line into Python?**

I notice that

```
# Load the .txt file in
myData = np.loadtxt('twenty_z_up.txt')
```

is quite "strict" in the sense that when the last incomplete line exists there, the file cannot be imported. The imported .txt file has to be a nice matrix.

**b.** Occasionally, I make timestamps on the first entry of a line for experiment purpose. Say I have my 1st timestamp at the start of line 2, and my 2nd stamp at the start of line 5. **How can I import only from line 2 to line 5 into Python?**

=============================== Updates: Q.a is solved ================================

```
myData = np.genfromtxt('fast_walking_pocket.txt', skip_footer=1)
```

will help discard the final incomplete row

Comment: @wim  Awesome! Q.a is solved. But what about Q.b? I have read the documentation of np.genfromtxt, but still no idea...

Comment: `numpy` doesn't come with a built-in solution for Qb. You have to preprocess your data file somehow, then feed the parsed results to `np.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt` (they accept a `StringIO` as input if that helps). The parsing steps would be something like 'for each line of f, yield the line if it's not a date; if it is, stop there but mark where we are'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your 'b' question.

Assume you have this file (called '/tmp/lines.txt'):

```
line 1
2013:10:15
line 3
line 4
2010:8:15
line 6
```

You can use the [linecache](http://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html?highlight=linecache) module:

```
>>> import linecache
>>> linecache.getline('/tmp/lines.txt', 2)
'2013:10:15\n'
```

So you can parse this time directly:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>>dt.datetime.strptime(linecache.getline('/tmp/lines.txt',2).strip(),'%Y:%m:%d')
datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 15, 0, 0)
```

***Edit***

Multiple lines:

```
>>> li=[]
>>> for i in (2,5):
...    li.append(linecache.getline('/tmp/lines.txt', i).strip())
... 
>>> li
['2013:10:15', '2010:8:15']
```

Or:

```
>>> lines={}
>>> for i in (2,5):
...    lines[i]=linecache.getline('/tmp/lines.txt', i).strip()
... 
>>> lines
{2: '2013:10:15', 5: '2010:8:15'}
```

Or a range:

```
>>> lines={}
>>> for i in range(2,6):
...    lines[i]=linecache.getline('/tmp/lines.txt', i).strip()
... 
>>> lines
{2: '2013:10:15', 3: 'line 3', 4: 'line 4', 5: '2010:8:15'}
```

Comment: OK. This is awesome for SINGLE line. but what if I want to extract line 2 all the way down to line 15?

Answer (score 3):

You can try [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which provides a use function [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) to load the data more easily.

Example data:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
a b c d e f g h i j
```

For your Q1, you can load the data by:

```
In [27]: import pandas as pd

In [28]: df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=' ', header=None, skipfooter=1)
```

[DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe) is a useful structure which can help you to 
process data easier. To get a numpy array, simply get the `values` attribute of the `DataFrame`.

```
In [33]: df.values
Out[33]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
        'n', 'o', 'p'],
       ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
        'n', 'o', 'p'],
       ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
        'n', 'o', 'p'],
       ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
        'n', 'o', 'p'],
       ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
        'n', 'o', 'p']], dtype=object)
```

For your Q2, you can get the second and the fifth line by

```
In [36]: df.ix[[1, 4]]
Out[36]:
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
1  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p
4  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p
```

Answer (score 1):

Question a:

```
np.genfromtxt('twenty_z_up.txt',skip_footer=1)
```

Qustion b:

```
np.genfromtxt('twenty_z_up.txt',skip_footer=1)[2:5]
```